# What's the font used in the "Walk it out" show poster?

Tags: font-identification

Can you please help me identify this glamorous show font used in the 'Walk it out' text?

Is it normal or a custom font?

[image]

Comment: Hi Rosie, because font-identification questions are not particularly useful for other people without some extra info, I added a little description to the title and content ("glamorous, although it might not be the correct word). Please feel free to edit if you have anything else you think might be helpful.

Comment: It would appear to be at least two separate, unrelated, fonts which have been altered to include some custom shapes.

Comment: "it" would be impact. Given the use of Impact, I assume "walk out" would also be some other system font. Clarendon is in the ballpark but not quite.

Answer (score 2):

As DA01 has commented, *it* is **Impact** — the digits (especially the 1) give it away. The other letters are based on **Georgia,** possibly made a little thicker and very closely tracked. Given the amount of work on the *a* of *walk,* including its tail, it seems a bit of pity not to have used a less common face.

[image: Example of Georgia and Impact]